# How to pass web services data to tableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

i am having webservices data as shown below in the shipping method

```
{ 
   "Flat": [
    {
      "price": "$5.00", 
      "id": 11, 
      "name": "Fixed"
    }
  ], 
  "United Parcel Service": [
    {
      "price": "$109.12", 
      "id": 1, 
      "name": "worldwide Expedited"
    }, 
    {
      "price": "$120.18", 
      "id": 2, 
      "name": "worldwide Express saver"
    }
  ]
}
```

i need to pass this data to the table view as shown below [image: here] can anyone help me how to implement this in table view dynamically that is flat and united parcel service both are dynamic and inside arrays also dynamic can anyone help me how to pass the data to table view to display as shown in image and my code is shown below

```
func shippingaddressURL() {
        let url = NSURL(string: self.url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
            self.shippingArray = (jsonObj!.value(forKey: "address") as? [[String: AnyObject]])!
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                    self.tableDetails.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }).resume()
    }
    func assignValuesToObjecs(arrayvalues: NSArray){
        (arrayvalues as NSArray).enumerateObjects({ (object, count, stop) in

            let Object :shippingObject = shippingObject()

            Object.name = (object as AnyObject) .value(forKey: "name") as! String
            Object.id = (object as AnyObject) .value(forKey: "id") as! NSInteger
            Object.price = (object as AnyObject).value(forKey: "price")as! String
            self.detailsArray.append(Object)
        })
    }

    func shippingmethodURL() {
        let url = NSURL(string: self.urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {    print(jsonObj!)
                self.arrayss = (jsonObj?.allKeys)! as! [String]
                //self.shippingArray = (jsonObj!.value(forKey: "Flat") as? [[String: AnyObject]])!
                self.assignValuesToObjecs(arrayvalues :(jsonObj?["Flat"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]! as? NSArray)!)
                self.assignValuesToObjecs(arrayvalues :(jsonObj?["United Parcel Service"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]! as? NSArray)!)
                self.methodArray = (jsonObj!.value(forKey: "United Parcel Service") as? [[String: AnyObject]])!
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                    self.tableDetails.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }).resume()
    }

    @IBAction func selectRadioButton(_ sender: KGRadioButton) {
        let chekIndex = self.checkIsRadioSelect.index(of: sender.tag)
        _ = self.checkIsButtonEnable.index(of: sender.tag)
        if sender.isSelected {

        } else{
            if(chekIndex == nil){
                self.checkIsRadioSelect.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                self.checkIsRadioSelect.append(sender.tag)
                self.checkIsButtonEnable.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                self.checkIsButtonEnable.append(sender.tag)
                self.tableDetails.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 5
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if section == 0 {
            return "SHIPPING ADDRESS"
        }
        else if section == 2{
            return "SHIPPING METHOD"
        }
        else{
            return ""
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int){

        let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
        header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
        header.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        header.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 17)
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        if (section == 0){
            return shippingArray.count
        }else if (section == 1){
            return 1
        }else if (section == 2) {
            return arrayss.count
        }else if (section == 3){
            return detailsArray.count
        }
        else {
            return 1
        }
    }

    @IBAction func deleteAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        shippingArray.remove(at:sender.tag)
        self.tableDetails.reloadData()
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       if indexPath.section == 0{
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! addressTableViewCell
            tableDetails.isHidden = false
            myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            let arr = shippingArray[indexPath.row]
            cell.deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.nameLabel.text = arr["name"] as? String
            cell.addressLabel.text = arr["address"]as? String
            let mobilenumber : Int =  arr["number"] as! Int
            cell.mobileNumberLabel.text = String(describing: mobilenumber)
            cell.radioButton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.editButton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.editButton.isHidden = true
            cell.deleteButton.isHidden = true
            let checkIndex = self.checkIsRadioSelect.index(of: indexPath.row)
            if(checkIndex != nil){
                cell.radioButton.isSelected = true
                cell.editButton.isHidden = false
                cell.deleteButton.isHidden = false
            }else{
                cell.radioButton.isSelected = false
                cell.editButton.isHidden = true
                cell.deleteButton.isHidden = true
            }
            return cell
        }else if indexPath.section == 1{
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "addresscell", for: indexPath) as! newAddressTableViewCell
            return cell
        }
        else if indexPath.section == 2{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "shippingcell", for: indexPath) as! shippingMethodTableViewCell
        cell.methodLabel.text = arrayss[indexPath.row]
        return cell
        }
       else if indexPath.section == 3{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "shippingTypeCell", for: indexPath) as! shippingMethodTypeTableViewCell
        var Object : shippingObject = shippingObject()
        Object = detailsArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.nameLabel.text = Object.name
        cell.priceLabel.text = Object.price
        return cell
        }
       else{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "continuecell", for: indexPath) as! continueTableViewCell
        return cell
        }
    }
```

Any help would be of great appreciation

Comment: Just use the Post notification observer and reload the table

Comment: no i am able to display the data but not in a proper manner as shown in the image in shipping method below @Sanjeetverma